# Not able to access variable in function after submitting form

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a variable which I get it from jquery $.post as a data.

```
$list_id = $_POST['lists'];
if(isset($_POST['email'])!=''){
$member_id = '58';
$this->member_lib->add_subscriber($member_id,$list_id);
}
```

Where as email is an input field in a form. When I submit the form, I will access the function add_subscriber with member id and list id. Member ID is working fine, where as $list_id is not passing into the function.

Any solution please.

Comment: `var_dump($_POST)` and see if you are getting all of them.

Comment: Please show your html. did you include something like `<input type="hidden"`?

Comment: I am getting list id above. But when I call the same inside if condition, it's not coming.

Comment: then the email is not set^

Comment: change `if(isset($_POST['email'])!=''){` to `if(isset($_POST['email'])){` or `if(empty($_POST['email'])''){`

Comment: Email is set and everything is printing inside that condition. Only list id is not coming.

Comment: your if statement will always equate to true even if your email is empty - isset always returns true or false so it will never = ''

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$_POST['email'] = 'asdsa';
$list_id = '123';
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
echo $list_id;
}
```

This is ok. However if it is not set like this

```
$list_id = '123';
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
echo $list_id;
}else{
echo "email is to set";

}
```

It will not echo your id which is what i am thinking is happening to you

Tested it [here](http://phptester.net/)

Answer (score 0):

`isset()` is use to check the variable is set or not. It is not use for comparision

```
$list_id = $_POST['lists'];
if(isset($_POST['email'])&& $_POST['email']!=""){// check your condition 
$member_id = '58';
$this->member_lib->add_subscriber($member_id,$list_id);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$list_id = $_POST['lists'];
if(isset($_POST['email'])){
$member_id = '58';
$this->member_lib->add_subscriber($member_id,$list_id);
}
```

Comment: your if statement will always equate to true even if your email is empty - isset always returns true or false so it will never = '' –  `Pete` please read this one

Answer (score 0):

To check the value for blank, its better to use `empty()` instead of `isset`. Because `isset` would return true, even if the value is set to `NULL`.

You can use ternary operator to check for values like:

```
$list_id = (!empty($_POST['list'])) ? $_POST['list'] : "";
```

So the code would be like this:

```
if(!empty($_POST['email'])) {
// all you functionality
}
```